# Validating quality and sound of mp3 files

Tags: mp3, batch, validation

I want to check the quality and sound volume of all my mp3 files.

Are there any processes to validate them in bulk?

I don't want to open each file individually and play them to check their quality and prefer a batch method.

How can I do this?

Comment: In What language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some mp3 libraries/tools support this task, have a look at [this](http://wiki.themixingbowl.org/MP3#MP3_Validation.2FFixing) for starters. If you want to write your own tool, I believe that many of the various LAME encoder api's support encoding.

There are also a number of other promising looking links that come up when googling 'mp3 validation'.